# Displaying monetary units in Nested If statements

Tags: java

This is my first post so I will try to be specific as possible I need help displaying the dollar amounts in nested if statements.

```
public class ComputeChange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double number = input.nextDouble();

        if (number == 0) {
            if (number > 0)
                System.out.print(number + " dollars");
        }
        else 
        System.out.print(number + " dollars");
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the information but my professor wants me to use plural and singular amounts but I fixed my code as best I could and here is what I came up with.

```
public class ComputeChange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double number = input.nextDouble();

        if (number > 1) {
            System.out.print(number + "dollars");
            if (number == 0)
                System.out.print(number + "");
            else
            System.out.print("1 dollar");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:After some trial and error, also a lot of help form the forums I finally am making progress. The only issue i`m having now is how do I display the multiple dollar amounts with out displaying the decimal.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputeChange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an amount in double, for example 11.56: " );
        double number = input.nextDouble();

        if (number == 1) {
            System.out.print("1 dollar");
        }
            else 
                if ( number > 1)
                    System.out.print(number / 1 + " dollars");
            if (number == 0)
                System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at your if conditions. If number is zero, if number is greater than zero. These conditions can never both be true so your print on line 8 can never execute.

Comment: English grammar nit picking but in English usage zero is bizarrely plural. So its 0.00 Dollars 1.00 Dollar, 2.00 Dollars. Jury is out as to the correct way to express 1.01 Dollar(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
if (number == 0) {
     if (number > 0)
          System.out.print(number + " dollars");
}
```

Will never print anything, as you only enter when number is equals to 0. Then you print if number higher then 0, but we already know it is equals to 0 so there will never be anything displayed.

However, I don't really understand why you don't simply replace all these validation with `System.out.print(number + " dollars");` as you always print the same thing anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the information but my professor wants me to use plural and singular amounts but I fixed my code as best I could and here is what I came up with.

Comment: @JWarrior777 Your new code is still wrong. You first check if number is greater then one, then if it is, you check if number == 0. But number can't be 0 and greater than one at the same time.